# RGB image reshaping by blocks in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have been trying to play around with for loops, permutations, etc. and I cannot solve this problem, help would be very appreciated.

I have a RGB image of which I have done processing on and is in this form:

```
image = [ 1 1
          1 1
          2 2
          2 2
          3 3
          3 3
          4 4
          4 4 ];
```

I want to transform the above matrix of this image into the actual image.
The final image would look like this:

```
new_image=[ 1 1 2 2
            1 1 2 2
            3 3 4 4
            3 3 4 4 ];
```

Obviously, the image i am working with is much larger than 4x4x3. How can I go about solving this problem?

EDIT:

Essential I am looking for an optimized way of doing the reshape command on "blocks". I am defining a block as something like so:

```
block1 = [ 1 1
           1 1];
```

and i have a block vector like so:

```
blockvector = [ block1
                block2
                block3
                block4 ];
```

I want to reshape this "block vector" in a similar fashion to the reshape command.

```
a=[ 1
    2
    3
    4];

 newa = reshape(a,[2,2])';
 % newa = [1 2
 %         3 4];
```

Comment: I have added more details to what I am referring to as in blocks and vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
% Input block size.
ibs = 3;

% Input.
input = [ 1 * ones(ibs); 2 * ones(ibs); 3 * ones(ibs); 4 * ones(ibs) ]

% Determine block size. 
bs = size(input, 2);

% Check format.
if (size(input, 1) != 4 * bs)
  disp('Wrong format.');
end

% Transpose input.
input = input.';

% Generate output.
output = [input(1:bs, 1:2*bs); input(1:bs, 2*bs+1:4*bs)]
```

Output:

```
input =
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   2   2   2
   2   2   2
   2   2   2
   3   3   3
   3   3   3
   3   3   3
   4   4   4
   4   4   4
   4   4   4

output =
   1   1   1   2   2   2
   1   1   1   2   2   2
   1   1   1   2   2   2
   3   3   3   4   4   4
   3   3   3   4   4   4
   3   3   3   4   4   4
```

I'm not satisfied by now. There must be a nicer solution for the last line of my script. Any improvements are highly welcom!